# Best practises: How to write the category R-mod

Tags: best-practices

What are the best practises for writing the category *R*-mod of modules over the ring *R*? Importantly, how should I write the dash? Is a text mode dash my only option, or is there a math mode workaround?

There are three common notational conventions, and I would like the most correct solution in each case:

- The “-mod” part is set in Roman. Should I write `R\textup{-}\mathrm{mod}`, `R\textrm{-mod}`, `\textrm{$R$-mod}`, or something else?
- The “-mod” part is in sans serif. Should I write `R\textup{-}\mathsf{mod}`, `R\textsf{-mod}`, `\textsf{$R$-mod}`, or something else?
- The entire thing is in bold: ***R*-mod**. Should I write `\textbf{\boldmath$R$-mod}`, or something else?

Obviously, I should actually write neither, but hide it away in a macro instead. The important thing to me is: What is the “right” way to type it?

Comment: There is probably not a **right** way to do it (in Journals it may even vary fron Journal to Journal). In general, one just have to be consistent.

Comment: Some solutions could be more reasonable than others. I only wish egreg had papers on arXiv; then we would have solution manuals for everything for the next 50-ish years. `;-)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an abstract command that you can tailor to the *desiderata* of journals or coauthors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% medium weight
\newcommand{\lmod}{{\operatorname{-mod}}}
% sans serif
%\newcommand{\lmod}{{\operatorname{\mathsf{-mod}}}}
% bold
%\newcommand{\lmod}{{\operatorname{\mathbf{-mod}}}}

\begin{document}

$R\lmod$

% sans serif
\renewcommand{\lmod}{{\operatorname{\mathsf{-mod}}}}
$R\lmod$

% bold
\renewcommand{\lmod}{{\operatorname{\mathbf{-mod}}}}
$R\lmod$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I slightly abuse `\operatorname` for its feature of producing a hyphen rather than a minus sign when `-` is input. The operator is braced to make it lose its spacing properties and so become an ordinary symbol.

If you plan to be decorating the ring symbol, you need to switch to a macro with argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

% medium weight
\newcommand{\lmod}[1]{#1{\operatorname{-mod}}}
% sans serif
%\newcommand{\lmod}[1]{#1{\operatorname{\mathsf{-mod}}}}
% bold
%\newcommand{\lmod}[1]{#1{\operatorname{\mathbf{-mod}}}}
% all bold
%\newcommand{\lmod}[1]{\bm{#1}{\operatorname{\mathbf{-mod}}}}

\begin{document}

$\lmod{R}$

% sans serif
\renewcommand{\lmod}[1]{#1{\operatorname{\mathsf{-mod}}}}
$\lmod{R}$

% bold
\renewcommand{\lmod}[1]{#1{\operatorname{\mathbf{-mod}}}}
$\lmod{R}$

% all bold
\renewcommand{\lmod}[1]{\bm{#1}{\operatorname{\mathbf{-mod}}}}
$\lmod{R}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only thing missing is that with your bold solution, the `R` does not become bold in ***R*-mod**, which is what I’d prefer. That is why I made my solution with `\boldmath` in the original post. How would you achieve this?

Comment: @Gaussler The symbol for the ring should always be the same, whether alone or in connection with “-mod”

Comment: I prefer making it bold, as I don’t use bold symbols for any other purpose anyway. Similarly, I want bold math in bold text, and I know a lot of people agree with me. `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler Boldfacing math in titles is a different problem altogether. If you’re adding `\boldmath` to `\bfseries`, you’ll get both parts bold anyway. I can’t understand why one should use different symbols for the same object in *normal* text.

Comment: Yes, I know and use the solution `\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}` and don’t understand why it’s not built into LaTeX. But still, my approach is that when categories are written in bold, the whole category name is written in bold, including the *R*. To me, *R* and ***R*** are not different symbols for the same object, they are the same symbol in different contexts (in and outside of category notation). Anyway, if you reluctantly accept my preferences for a moment, I guess you would write something like `\text{\boldmath$R$}{\operatorname{\mathbf{-mod}}}` (hidden away in macros, obviously)?

Comment: @Gaussler I added the code. Why isn't `\boldmath` done automatically by `\bfseries`? Because people don't want it, generally speaking. I'd be in favor of an “official” interface for doing it. Note that `\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}` is *not* the best way to do that.

Comment: Strange indeed. Anyway, thanks for the updated answer. In any case, I am defining the macros completely differently, as my own math notation is based on SemanTeX, with a solution like in section 11.1 in https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/semantex/semantex.pdf.

Comment: Then what *is* the best way to add `\boldmath` to `\bfseries`?

Comment: @Gaussler With LaTeX 2020-10-01, you do `\AddToHook{bfseries}{\boldmath}`.

Comment: One suggestion: if you use `\boldsymbol` in place of `\bm`, it will work not only with the `bm` package, but with any document that uses `amsmath` or `unicode-math`.

Comment: @Davislor `\providecommand{\bm}{\boldsymbol}` is handier. ;-)