# Weird behaviour of \operatorname{\text{$...$}}

Tags: math-operators

Why is the `*` raised in the first example, unlike the second one?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$ \operatorname{\text{$*$}hello} $
vs.
$ *\operatorname{hello} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's by design of `\operatorname`. In the documentation of `amsopn` we read:

> In operator names, it is sometimes desired to have text-mode
> punctuation characters such as *-/:’. Because the body of an operator
> name is set in math mode, these few punctuation characters will not
> come out right (wrong symbol/and or wrong spacing). The purpose of
> \newmcodes@ is to make them act like their normal text versions.

The definition `\newmacodes@` is:

`\gdef\newmcodes@{\mathcode‘\’39\mathcode‘\*42\mathcode‘\."613A%`

So, the mathcode of `*` is changed in `\operatorname`.

Comment: Yes, but I’m quite surprised that using `\text{$...$}` did not override this behaviour.

Comment: @Gaussler the surprising thing is to use `\text` in `\operatorname` that use is unexpected (to say the least!)

Comment: I have added a precision to my answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand your surprise. Using `\text{$...$}` was a failed attempt to override the mentioned behaviour. The `*` I am inserting in the operator name is part of a bigger construction.

Comment: @Gaussler Instead of operatorname, have you considered `\mathop{*$\mathrm{hello}$}\nolimits`?` Or the operator font, if different?

Comment: @Davislor I use it as part of [this construction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567886/19809) by egreg, so I would have preferred to just write the `*` inside the `\operatorname` and get it to work. Of course, there are obvious workarounds available, I’m aware of that. I was mostly just surprised that my `\text{$...$}` workaround did not work as expected, so I decided to ask why. `;-)`

Answer (score 7):

The operations for `\operatorname` and `\DeclareMathOperator` do `\newmcodes@`, which is defined as

```
% amsopn.sty, line 30:
\gdef\newmcodes@{\mathcode`\'39\mathcode`\*42\mathcode`\."613A%
  \ifnum\mathcode`\-=45 \else
    \mathchardef\std@minus\mathcode`\-\relax
  \fi
  \mathcode`\-45\mathcode`\/47\mathcode`\:"603A\relax}
```

and going to text mode with `\text` doesn't reverse the assignment. The asterisk is now taken from the text font, the same as used for the letters.

Perhaps `\text` should revert the assignment, but it's been like this for more than a quarter of a century, so…

On the other hand, you can notice that there's no setting to `\ast`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\bad}{{*}hello}
\DeclareMathOperator{\good}{{\ast}hello}

\begin{document}

This has a raised asterisk $\bad$

This has a centered asterisk $\good$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since you say you are trying to work around the way `\operatorname` handles punctuation, you might have an XY problem. Defining a new command that typesets with the same font and spacing, but does not do that, might work for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\varopname[1]{\mathop{\operator@font #1}\nolimits}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\varopname{*hello}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern sample]

You might also define a version without `\nolimits` and an equivalent to `\DeclareMathOperator`.